# Deleted libgtk-4-1 caused missing GUI and ozone platform initialization failure

Tags: command-line, display, xserver

I recently attempted to upgrade the libgtk-4-1 library to the latest version on my system. In order to do so, I used the command '`sudo apt remove libgtk-4-1`' to remove the previous version. However, after the removal, I am no longer able to see the GUI interface and only a terminal-like interface is visible.

When I try to launch applications, I receive the following error message:
`ozone_platform_x11.cc(239) Missing x server or $DISPLAY` and `the platform failed to initialize.`

I am unsure how to resolve this issue and restore the GUI interface. Could someone please provide guidance on how to fix this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Os : Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64
Kernel: 6.2.0-20 generic 
Shell : bash 5.2.15
Codename: lunar
```

Thank you in advance[image]
[image]

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details, thus our ability to provide package advice is limited (*packages are built for specific releases & we don't know yours, thus cannot know what actual results will be for your unstated OS/release*), however you removed a package that much of GNOME or the default Desktop of Ubuntu uses thus inability to use a GUI maybe expected.  (*For my release; `gnome-shell` is one package that depends on it for example thus I'd expect issues with using GNOME Shell or Ubuntu Desktop as you experienced*)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell
```

This fixed it for me. Thanks @guiverc

Comment: Use `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` to restore the default interface